# On group automorphism of subgroup a group $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $H$ be a subgroup of $G$. When is $\rm{Aut}(H)$ a subgroup of $\rm{Aut}(G)$?

Comment: Generally speaking a question of this type has a shot at a reasonable answer if there is a canonical map $\text{Aut}(H) \to \text{Aut}(G)$ and you want to ask when this map is injective. But in this case there is no such map. Instead there is a canonical map the other way from the subgroup of automorphisms of $G$ preserving $H$ to the group of automorphisms of $H$. So it's not clear to me what you want: do you just want to know when there exists, abstractly, an injection of $\text{Aut}(H)$ into $\text{Aut}(G)$? Do you want this injection to land only in the subgroup of $\text{Aut}(G)$...

Comment: ...which preserves $H$ and to respect the action on $H$? (That would require that you could somehow extend automorphisms of $H$ to automorphisms of $G$ in some reasonable way.) There are lots of things you could want and I doubt there is an easy answer to any of the possible forms of this question.

Comment: @Ali Gholamian: Please consider registering in the site; that will make it easier to keep track of your questions.

Comment: @Ali Gholamian: As above, there is a lot of thing this qestion brings here. You certainly know that $\mathbb{Z}_{6}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{3}$ know just one group as their Automorphism Group.

Comment: This question on Mathoverflow is related: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/9749/characterising-extendable-automorphisms

Comment: A partial but also quite trivial answer to this question is: If $\text{Out}(H)=0$, then $\text{Aut}(H)=\text{Inn}(H) \leq \text{Inn}(G) \leq \text{Aut}(G)$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan  One consider a similar question in term of shoer exact sequence (in various category):let $0\to A \to B \to C \to 0$  is  a short exact sequence. when Aut(A) is embedable in Aut B?

Answer (score -1):

The restriction of an automorphism of G to H is an automorphism of H requires that H is a characteristic  sub-groupe  in G, in this case the restriction morphism of Aut (G)   to Aut (H) has a sense and is an epimorphism. In  this cas it is hoped that Aut (G) is a direct product  of Aut (H)  ie  the exacte sequence

I said that a sufficient condition for the $Aut(H)$
to be  injected into $Aut(G)$ is that $H$  a characteristic
subgroup in $G$ and the  exact  short sequence:  $ ker(rest)
\hookrightarrow Aut(G)\rightarrow Aut(H)$(this last morphism is
the epimorphism restriction) split. Then a partial answer that I
deduced from the last comment given to this issue as similar
question in terms of exact short sequence of groups is this: under
the condition H to be a direct factor of G and simultaneously a
 characteristic subgroup in G, then $Aut(H)$ is injected into
$Aut(G)$. This injection may in no case be canonical (as Aut (.)
Is not a functor), but the restriction is canonical and has a
sense here because H supposed characteristic.

Prove: Suppose $G=H\times K$
and $H$ characteristic in $G$, so the restriction morphism
$Aut(G)\rightarrow Aut(H)$ is an epimorphism $f\mapsto f_H $, it
can viewed in this situation as the composite morphism $p_H\circ
f\circ i_H : H\hookrightarrow H\times K \rightarrow H\times
K\times \rightarrow H $ where $i_H$ the canonical
monomorphism,$f\in Aut(H\times K)$ and  $p_H$ the canonical
projection. Since $H$ characteristic in $H\times K$ then  $K$ is
also characteristic in $H\times K$ because for any $f\in
Aut(H\times K)$ the composite morphism $p_K\circ f$ left via the
naturel projection $p_K:H\times K\rightarrow K$. and so we
obtained   the direct product $Aut(H\times K)\simeq Aut(H)\times
Aut(K)$ with the isomorphism restriction $f\mapsto (f_H,f_K)$ and
of course the already exact short sequence split.

Comment: there are error  in the kernel i am sorry, The  kernel is not o but the sub-group of aut(G) that have restrection to H the identite of H. so the conclusion is not true but speking Aut(H) sub-groupe of Aut(G) requires H characteristic and the obouve exacte sequence split, thanks

Comment: I mean all automorphisms of G for have the morphism  from Aut (G) in the Aut(H)  by restriction. I  have problem to translat my idea in english. Sorry and thanks

Comment: As a non-trivial
example, take G a finite nilpotent group and H a p-Sylow subgroup
of G then $Aut(H)$ is a direct product factor of $Aut(G)$