# If $A$ is a subgroup of $B$, just it hold that $\text{Aut}(A)$ is a subgroup of $\text{Aut}(B)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, automorphism-group

Let $\text{Aut}(G)$ denote the group of automorphisms of $G$ and let $A\subseteq B$ denote $A$ is a subgroup of $B$. Does the following hold:

$$A\subseteq B\implies \text{Aut}(A)\subseteq \text{Aut}(B)$$

If not, is there a necessary and sufficient condition for this to hold?

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11168/290189) Please read [this post](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/290189) and the others there for information on writing a good question for this site. In particular, people will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include some motivation, and an explanation of your own attempts.

Comment: Could you let me know how I can improve this quesiton?

Comment: This question is hard, and there's not a simple answer. In general, there's no reason a function preserving only the $A$ structure should extend to one preserving all the extra  $B$ structure. You can find a discussion about for which automorphisms this is possible [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/9749/characterising-extendable-automorphisms), but the answer may not satisfy you

Comment: So I suppose the answer is "no", and for the follow-up about a necessary/sufficient condition, the answer is "not a simple one"

Comment: @HallaSurvivor, thanks, this is exactly the kind of thing I was looking for.

Comment: I'll add it as an answer, then

Comment: Yes, I will accept that, thank you

Comment: The same question can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/100687/on-group-automorphism-of-subgroup-a-group-g). I think it's worth keeping this question open, however, so that explicit examples can be stated.

Comment: Note that you are trying to deduce something about the symmetries of a larger object from the symmetries of a smaller one. It is then possible that the smaller, simpler, object will have more symmetry than the larger more complicated one in which it is embedded (the reverse also could be true - symmetries could be added). You will know from the answers that there are counterexamples: I'm just adding an intuition as to why they might exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is certainly not true in general.

For a counterexample take $A:=S_6$ whose automorphism group is well-known to have order $2\cdot 6!$; and take $B:=S_7$ whose automorphism group is well-known to have order $7!=7\cdot 6!$.

Answer (score 2):

This question is hard, and there's not a simple answer. In general, there's no reason a function preserving only the $A$ structure should extend to one preserving all the extra $B$ structure. You can find a discussion about which automorphisms *can* be extended [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/9749/characterising-extendable-automorphisms), but the answer may not satisfy you.

So I suppose the answer is "no", and the answer to the follow-up question about a necessary and sufficient condition is "not a simple one".

There is also some good discussion in the comments of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/100687/on-group-automorphism-of-subgroup-a-group-g)

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Can you give an example of $A$ a subgroup of $B$, and the automorphism group of $A$ not a subgroup of the sutomorphism group of $B$?

Comment: GerryMyerson, good question. @HallaSurvivor, I would also like to know about that before accepting the answer. Thanks

Comment: Not off the top of my head. I'll ask [sage](https://www.sagemath.org/) about it tomorrow. It's easy to see that for simple cases $\text{Aut}(A)$ is not _naturally_ a subgroup of $\text{Aut}(B)$. But the few examples I tried all worked (though I suspect this is an accident of small groups)

Comment: thanks for this, I look forward to hearing more tomorrow.

Comment: @GerryMyerson : I have offered an example.

Comment: A smaller example is $A=C_2 \times C_2$ as a subgroup of $B=D_8$ (dihedral of order $8$). $A$ has an automorphism of order $3$ that does not extend to $D_8$.

Comment: @DerekHolt I think there's an even simpler one. Consider the map $$f: C_2\times C_2\rightarrow C_2\times C_4:(x,y)\mapsto (x,2y).$$ If we let $B=C_2\times C_4$ and $A=im(f)$, then there is an automorphism of $A$ swapping $(1,0)$ and $(0,2)$ but that can't extend to an automorphism of $B$ since $(0,2)$ can be divided by $2$ in $B$ but $(1,0)$ can't. Here everything is abelian and it's easier to check non-extendability.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Agreed, but I am convinced that is a simpler example. They are both instances of embeddings of $C_2 \times C_2$ in groups of order 8.

Comment: @DerekHolt Sure, it's certainly not much of a difference, but for me at least I find it a bit easier to think about.